# React.js: Module not found: Can't resolve '...' in '...'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I’m new to React and I have to compile a code written in react.js into an app. I’m experiencing an error in my main js file, the one with the app’s code (named index.js). I try to use some info located in another folder but it seems this creates the following error:

> ./src/index.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'website/scentdesigner-master/frontend/src/Redux/Actions/login' in '/Users/user_name/Desktop/21g_app/src'

(the error is displayed on my server)

I’ve checked about a dozen of times that the route to the folder is correct so I’m pretty sure that’s not the problem. 
I have also installed all the necessary npm modules on my laptop so I don't think that's the problem either (when I used terminal, I installed them under my app's folder).

- Here is the line that triggers the error message in my index.js file:

  ```
  import { loginUpdateOutCome } from 'website/scentdesigner-master/frontend/src/Redux/Actions/login';
  ```
- And here is the "login" file it is importing from:

  ```
  import AppFlowActions from '../../constants';

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} data
   */
  export function loginRequest(data) {
    return ({ type: AppFlowActions.LOGIN_REQUEST, data });
  }

  export function loginCompleted(data) {
    return ({ type: AppFlowActions.LOGIN_COMPLETE, data });
  }

  export function loginUpdateOutCome(data) {
    return ({ type: AppFlowActions.UPDATE_OUTCOME, data });
  }

  export function loginUpdateUserInfo(data) {
    return ({ type: AppFlowActions.UPDATE_USER_INFO, data });
  }
  /**
   *
   * @param {*} data
   */
  export function logoutRequest() {
    return ({ type: AppFlowActions.LOGOUT_REQUEST });
  }
  ```
- This file itself imports some info from an another file located in the "constants" folder which is just a few lines of code defining some stuff under constants. Pretty sure the problem is not there either as this code was written by experts who currently run the website with the same code.

My guess is that the error probably comes from my environment but I have no clue of what it could possibly be.

Thank you in advance for your help if you somehow manage to find a solution to this.

Comment: assuming your index.js file is in the same directory of website directory add import {...} from './website/...' to your index.js.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your help. Just tried that but the same error is displayed.

Comment: show your src directoy

Comment: 100% sure your import path is wrong as @F.bernal suggested. I suspect the right path seems to be `'./Redux/Actions/login'`.

Comment: @Dez I tried that but same error message.

Comment: Here is where the file is located: /Users/user_name/Desktop/21g_app/src/website/scentdesigner-master/frontend/src/Redux/Actions/

Comment: I believe u are using webpack and your configuration settings are false. can u push your webpack and babel.rc

Comment: Try: `import { loginUpdateOutCome } from './website/scentdesigner-master/frontend/src/Redux/Actions/login';`.  If that doesn't work you would have to share the configuration of your project as requested in order to users to be able to help you.